# I have duplicate record in my grid view using LINQ?

Tags: asp.net, linq

I don't know if this is the right way to do this but, I join three tables 
to get the follow select new information. I see the information but each record is showing up multiply times example:

[image]

```
var q = from u in entities.problems
        join c in entities.my_aspnet_users
            on u.user_id equals c.id into resultQuery
        from r in resultQuery
        join p in entities.problem_history
            on r.id equals p.user_id
        orderby u.problem_reported_datetime ascending
        select new {
            r.name, u.problem_description,
            u.problem_reported_datetime, p.problem_status_code
        };
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this

Comment: I see different statuses so it is definately not the same data.

Comment: Its probably due to your join. Is there a 1-1 relationship between id and user_id?

Comment: Thanks jrummell I added a where clause.  Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It's not something you are doing wrong; you could add a .Distinct() method call at the end, but the underlying problem is the problem status code field; it has two different values for the same record.  So you need to figure out how you want to display those statuses... you can display the first one, concatenate them, etc.  You can achieve that in LINQ by grouping your results together, or using a let statement to perform a subquery to get the related problem status codes.

HTH.

Comment: Just as something to note - the Distinct() method won't work unless you create an IEqualityComparer that dicates what fields actually need to be distinct. Out of the box, .Distinct() only check an entity's key for distinction.